# "char(a)" issue in C++

Tags: c++

I don't know why the code below works? and why is it completed compile?

Code : `b = char(a);`

I wonder if it's one of the ways to use "char" or if it's a bug.

```
printf("Start Test\n");

int a = 0xF30;
char b = 0;
char c = 0;
char d = 0x30;
char e = 0xF30;
b = char(a);        // <- Why??
c = (char)a;    

printf("%c, %c, %c, %c, %c\n", a, b, c, d, e);

printf("End Test\n");

getchar();

return 0;
```

Console Result

```
Start Test

0, 0, 0, 0, 0

End Test
```

Comment: Is it C or is it C++?

Comment: It's valid C++ but invalid C

Comment: To expand on my earlier comment, it's almost never a good idea to tag a question as both C and C++. Specify the language that you actually used to compile the code. Some code is valid C and C++ (yours isn't, and that's the key to answering your question), but the language used is typically determined by which compiler you're using and by the name of the source file.

Comment: cpp file / vs2017

Comment: With which compiler do you compile this code? Is it a .c- or a .cpp-file?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: You downvoted the question for a problem that it no longer has because you fixed it yourself. A downvote usually indicates a problem that the OP could correct. In this case, there's nothing the OP could do. Please consider withdrawing your downvote.

Comment: @RobertS: Answered in the comment before yours.

Comment: Please consider adding meaningful titles - "char() issue please help me" is not at all indicative of the problem you have. I've removed the pleading, but it could still be improved. "Why does a variable of type X allow an assignment to a value of type Y" could be a good format (with, obviously, the actual types inserted into that sentence). I don't understand the problem though, so I will leave someone else to make that edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ (unlike C) has more than one notation for explicit type conversions (casts).

C++ inherits C's cast notation:

```
int i = some_value;
char c;
c = (char)i;
```

It also has a functional notation:

```
c = char(i);
```

as well as several cast operators which are more restrictive than a C-style cast.

```
c = static_cast<char>(i);
```

These all (in this case) specify the same conversion.

Note that for conversions between numeric types, a cast is not necessary (and is probably a bad idea). An assignment (or a function argument, or a `return` statement) will perform an implicit conversion, so you can just write:

```
c = i;
```

By using a cast, you risk specifying the wrong type, resulting in an additional implicit conversion and possibly a wrong result:

```
c = (unsigned char)i; // explicitly converts to unsigned char,
                      // then implicitly converts to char
```

Answer (score 3):

This is covered under the section ["Explicit type conversion (functional notation)"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.type.conv) in the C++11 standard.

Given your code,

```
b = char(a);
```

is the same as

```
b = a;
```

More generally, it can be used to explicitly convert an expression to another type. E.g.

```
b = char(10);
```

Here, 10 is of type `int`. By using `char(10)`, 10 is explicitly converted to `char` before the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, `b = char(a);` It is Invalid operation in c, but valid in c++.In c++ it will be considered as a ascii value. so it is same as this notation `b = (char)a;`

Comment: C++ does not specify ASCII.